# Retornar valores se algum registro não existir

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Eu tenho as tabelas:

```
tabelaUm
[id] [nome]
1    nome1
2    nome2

tabelaDois
[id] [idTabelaUm] [nome]
1    1            nome1
1    1            nome2
1    1            nome3
1    2            nome4
1    2            nome5
1    2            nome6
```

Minha query:

```
SELECT t1.nome AS n1, t2.nome AS n2
FROM tabelaUm AS t1
LEFT JOIN tabelaDois AS t2 ON 1
WHERE t1.nome = :foo
AND t2.nome = :bar
```

Resultado:

```
(':foo' => 'nome1', ':bar' => 'nome3') retorna 'n1' => 'nome1', 'n2' => 'nome3'
(':foo' => 'nome2', ':bar' => 'nome7') retorna empty
(':foo' => 'nome3', ':bar' => 'nome6') retorna empty
(':foo' => 'nome4', ':bar' => 'nome9') retorna empty
```

É possível fazer com que retorne de seguinte forma?

```
(':foo' => 'nome1', ':bar' => 'nome3') retorna 'n1' => 'nome1', 'n2' => 'nome3'
(':foo' => 'nome2', ':bar' => 'nome7') retorna 'n1' => 'nome2', 'n2' => empty
(':foo' => 'nome3', ':bar' => 'nome6') retorna 'n1' => empty, 'n2' => 'nome6'
(':foo' => 'nome4', ':bar' => 'nome9') retorna 'n1' => empty, 'n2' => empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconheço a forma de declarar a cláusula do join como você usou (`tabelaUm AS t1 LEFT JOIN tabelaDois AS t2 ON`***`1`***), mas, ignorando isso, o resultado não está de acordo com o que você espera porque apesar de você declarar o join como `LEFT`, na cláusula `WHERE` você está impondo que `T2.NOME` **precisa** ter um valor e que ele deve ser igual a `:bar`. Na prática isso contradiz o *left* declarado anteriormente e o SGBD simplesmente converte o seu `LEFT JOIN` em um join comum para otimização, [segundo a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/left-join-optimization.html).

Para contornar, basta você incluir na clausula `WHERE` a possibilidade de `T2.Nome` não existir:

```
SELECT t1.nome AS n1, t2.nome AS n2
FROM tabelaUm AS t1
    LEFT JOIN tabelaDois AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.idTabelaUm
WHERE t1.nome = :foo
    AND (t2.nome is null OR t2.nome = :bar)
```